# Inspect requests from android in Node-inspector

Tags: node.js, debugging, node-inspector

I'm running a local nodejs server on my computer. I want to debug the requests sent from android device with Node-inspector. Is it possible? 
If it does, what is the ip and port i need to send the requests to?
If it does not, how can I debug requests from android sent directly to my computers IP?

Thanks!

Comment: If your node server is enabled for debugging, then you can attach a node-inspector debugger to your ndoejs server from any computer that can reach the debugging port of your server (e.g. you could run node-inspector) on your own computer where the server is.  You could then set breakpoints in the request handlers and debug any request sent from your Android device.  There are lots of tutorials on setting up your node server to be debuggable with node-inspector.  Any of those should work for you.

Comment: Debugging the app from your computer or the phone is no difference for the server. Just set a breakpoint as you were testing from your computer and open the ip-address of your computer on your phone. It should stop at the breakpoint.

Comment: It doesnt work. I am using ionic, and every request i send fails (err_connection_timed_out), so I thaught that it might be an issue with the node inspector. I want to debug the server, not the android app if it wasnt clear...

Comment: That much was clear, i think. What the comment above is saying is that you should be able to set a breakpoint in the request handler of your server and debug it with node-inspector. Where the request is coming from (a browser, an android app, etc..) is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: My problem was that I was listenning to 127.0.0.1 and NOT to my actual ip, when i started the server. When I started to listen to my actual IP, everything worked perfectly.
Thanks!